# Include issue in JavaScript with arrays

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with a simple logic in JavaScript, that checks for digits occurrence in an arrays. The problem is defined as follows:

No match 0

Make certain that your application accommodates repeating digits. For example, if a user guesses 1, 2, and 3, and the randomly generated digits are 1, 1, and 1, do not give the user credit for three correct guesses - just one. Save the file as Lottery.

The main issue is happening at `if (lotteryResults.includes(guesses[j]))`. I don't know why it is working when I hard code a value in the `includes`.

Comment: You said you are having an issue and where it is occurring. But you did not mention what issue you are facing!

Comment: Despite guessing the correct number(s), it is still showing me won zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `prompt()` returns a string that should be converted to number. You can use `+` to convert it to number

```
for (var i = 1; i <= TIMES; i++) {
  var userInput = +prompt("Enter a guess");
  guesses.push(userInput);
}
```

And second problem is that you are comparing arrays `guesses == lotteryResults`. This will never return `true`. You can use `join()` and then compare

```
if (guesses.join('') == lotteryResults.join(''))
```

```js
var TIMES = 3;

var userFirstGuess;
var userSecondGuess;
var userThirdGuess;

var guesses = [];

var firstRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
var secondRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
var thirdRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= TIMES; i++) {
  var userInput = +prompt("Enter a guess");
  guesses.push(userInput);
}

alert(guesses);

var winTen = 10;
var WinHun = 100;
var winThoun = 1000;
var winMillion = 10000;
var winZero = 0;

var lotteryResults = [];
lotteryResults.push(firstRandom);
lotteryResults.push(secondRandom);
lotteryResults.push(thirdRandom);

if (guesses.join('') == lotteryResults.join('')) {
  alert("You have won: $ " + winMillion);
} else {
  var matchCount = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < guesses.length; j++) {
    if (lotteryResults.includes(guesses[j])) {
      matchCount++
      var index = lotteryResults.indexOf(guesses[j]);
      lotteryResults.splice(index);
      alert('Lottery ' + lotteryResults);
    }
  }

  switch (matchCount) {
    case 0:
      alert("You have won: $ " + winZero);
      break;
    case 1:
      alert("You have won: $ " + winTen);
      break;
    case 2:
      alert("You have won: $ " + winHun);
      break;
    case 3:
      alert("You have won: $ " + winThoun);
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering your current problem, the `prompt` writes entries of type `string` into `guesses`. And after that you're trying to find a number inside.

What I suggest is to `parseInt` the `guesses[j]`

```
if (lotteryResults.includes(parseInt(guesses[j])) {
```

Another issue I found is

```
if (guesses == lotteryResults) {
```

You can't compare arrays like that. You might try

```
if (guesses.join('') === lotteryResults.join('')) {
```

**EDIT** Example:

```js
console.log([7,3,1] === [7,3,1])
console.log([7,3,1].join('') === [7,3,1].join(''))
```

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. We can't compare arrays. Thanks for telling +1

Answer (score 1):

Here   `var userInput = prompt("Enter a guess"); console.log(typeof userInput) // returns string`. So when you are checking `lotteryResults.includes(guesses[j])` it returns `false` for example  `lotteryResults.includes("4") // returns false`.

You can fix your code as :

`var userInput = prompt("Enter a guess");
 guesses.push(Number(userInput));`

OR

`var userInput = prompt("Enter a guess");
 guesses.push(parseInt(userInput));`

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the prompt values to Numbers just add + before gusses[j]
try my code:

```js
  for (var j = 0; j < guesses.length; j++) {
    if (lotteryResults.includes(+guesses[j])) {
      matchCount++
      var index = lotteryResults.indexOf(+guesses[j]);
      if(index !== -1){
      lotteryResults.splice(index,1);
      }
      alert('Lottery ' + lotteryResults);
    }
  }
```